# Como fazer para alternar entre versão nativa do php para uma versão instalada pelo brew no maverick?

Tags: php, nginx

Tenho feito atualização pelo **brew** com o **php** mas quando  uso `phpinfo()` ainda está na versão do **php** do sistema, como alternar ou alterar?

Comment: Só uma pergunta: para evitar esse tipo de coisa, não seria mais interessante se você começasse a trabalhar com Vagrant? Hoje mesmo tive esse tipo de problema e usando Vagrant as coisas ficaram muito mais fáceis.

Answer (score 1):

Vê em qual pasta está o php que tu instalou pelo brew e modifica o arquivo de configuração do servidor web para usar os modulos de lá.

Caso queria por linha de comando apague se tiver entrada em /usr/bin/php e faça um link simbólico da versão que tu instalou pelo brew